# libclang parsing generates wrong output

Tags: parsing, llvm, clang

I am trying to build a small parsing program using libclang.

The source file to parse (Node.h):

```
#pragma once

struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

The main program simple invokes the clang parser and walks all elements in the AST:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);

    const char *filename = "Node.h";

    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, filename, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);

    CXCursor rootCursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TU);

    clang_visitChildren(rootCursor, printVisitor, NULL);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);
    return 0;
}
```

The visitor:

```
CXChildVisitResult printVisitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data) {

    CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cursor);
    CXSourceLocation startLocation = clang_getRangeStart(range);
    CXSourceLocation endLocation = clang_getRangeEnd(range);

    CXFile file;
    unsigned int line, column, offset;
    clang_getInstantiationLocation(startLocation, &file, &line, &column, &offset);
    printf("Start: Line: %u Column: %u Offset: %u\n", line, column, offset);
    clang_getInstantiationLocation(endLocation, &file, &line, &column, &offset);
    printf("End: Line: %u Column: %u Offset: %u\n", line, column, offset); 

    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}
```

However, the output shows some weird parts:

```
Start: Line: 99 Column: 9 Offset: 3160 
End: Line: 99 Column: 122 Offset: 3273 
Kind: A field (in C) or non-static data member (in C++) in a struct.
Filename: (null)
```

Where does this come from?

When removing the pragma, nothing changes. The same happens with a completely empty header file to parse.

Do I have to bypass all found node in the AST until I get a "first statement"- or "first expression"-node?

Answer (score 0):

I got the TU like this:

CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Index, 0, argv, argc,
                                                    0, 0,
                                                    CXTranslationUnit_None);

And, then I run your testcase(Node.h), got the result:

Start: Line: 3 Column: 1 Offset: 14

End: Line: 6 Column: 2 Offset: 67

Start: Line: 4 Column: 5 Offset: 32

End: Line: 4 Column: 14 Offset: 41

Start: Line: 5 Column: 5 Offset: 47

End: Line: 5 Column: 22 Offset: 64

Start: Line: 5 Column: 12 Offset: 54

End: Line: 5 Column: 16 Offset: 58

I think the result is correct. You can try it like this.